# scope of variable out of function in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, alert

This is simple code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
        var genvalue="";    
    $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
    genvalue = $(this).val();
    alert (genvalue);
    }); 
alert (genvalue);   
     //genvalue = $('#gender').val();
//alert (genvalue);

value = $("#edu_det1").val();

more code.................goes ......
```

I want value of `alert (genvalue)` to alert even if it is not call by click event but when radio button is click the value alerted by first alert while for second out of function is not alerting correct value. I give empty values.

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you want here... Perhaps you can try re-writing your post and explain what exactly is going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The genvalue is alerted when the radio button is clicked and also as soon as the document ready event is fired. The second is fired first and it will not have any value since you declared at top as

```
var genvalue="";
```

If you want to alert the correct value either way, try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NU9m6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    var genvalue=$("input:radio[name=gender]").val();

     $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
      genvalue = $(this).val();
        alert (genvalue);
       });
     alert (genvalue);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has functionscope - the lifetime of a variable is limited to the execution of it's enclosing function.

You create a new variable inside your click function. Instead you should assign a value to the already existing variable. So you need to write

```
var genvalue="";
$("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
    /* omit the "var" to assign a value to the variable genvalue*/
    genvalue = $(this).val();
});
alert(genvalue) // alerts genvalue, in this case probably ""
                // because the alert gets called before the click-handler fired
```

instead of:

```
var genvalue="";
$("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
    /* This creates a new variable which is only visible in the click-function */
    var genvalue = $(this).val();
});
alert(genvalue) // will always alert "" and never the value assigned to
                // the var inside your click handler function
```

Answer (score 0):

genvalue is outside the scope of the function as you define it with `var` inside the function.

```
var genvalue="";

$(document).ready(function() {       
    genvalue="";
    $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
        genvalue = $(this).val();
        alert (genvalue);
    }); 

alert (genvalue);   
//genvalue = $('#gender').val();
//alert (genvalue);

value = $("#edu_det1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your genvalue variable to be available outside of your document ready function define it outside the function.

```
var genvalue="";
$(document).ready(function() {       
   $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
   genvalue = $(this).val();
   alert (genvalue);
});
alert (genvalue);
```

Also, once you've defined your variable you don't need to use var again.

Answer (score 0):

The second time you call `alert` is not going to give the right values because it's **being called when the document is loaded**.

This means that there is *no possible way* the the `click` callback has been called on your **radio button** and so the `genvalue` variable will be undefined.

You've also declared `genvalue` in your function with the `var` keyword, which will **scope** it to that function body, making it inaccessible from outside the `click` callback function.